# Writing an array to a CSV File - Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have 24 elements in an array I am looking to write to a CSV file to be opened in Excel.

When I run my program, it creates a CSV file in my Netbeans project folder. However, when I open the CSV file - it is blank.

In my main method, I show the user the array and then call the writeCSV method as shown below:

```
    //show the user the sorted array
    System.out.println( "The sorted array is: ");
    for ( int i=0; i<24; i++)      
        System.out.println( "\t" + course2[i].toString() );

    //write the data from the duplicate array to a CSV file
    System.out.println("\nWriting data from Course array to CSV File.");
    writeCSV(course2, count);
```

The writeCSV method is pasted below:

```
    //write from duplicate array of courses to a CSV file
    public static void writeCSV(Course[] courseArray, int count) throws Exception {

    //create a File class object and give the file the name employees.csv
    java.io.File courseCSV = new java.io.File("courses.csv");

    //Create a Printwriter text output stream and link it to the CSV File
    java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(courseCSV);

    //Iterate the elements actually being used
    for (int i=0; i < count ; i++) {
        outfile.write(courseArray[i].toCSVString());

    }//end for

    outfile.close();
    } //end writeCSV()
```

The writeCSV method above calls the toCSVString method which is defined in a class I created named Course. I pasted this method below:

```
// method to return properties as a CSV string on one line
//public String toCSVString(Course c){
public String toCSVString() {
    String record = campus + ","
                  + course + ","
                  + section + ","
                  + crn + ","
                  + credits + ","
                  + time + ","
                  + days + "\n";

    return record;
} //end toCSVString()
```

My code runs flawlessly up until I have to write the array to a CSV file. This is when it creates the blank CSV file. This makes me believe I have an error within my toCSVString method or the writeCSV method I believe. Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure count is set correctly and not 0? This would be compatible with your problem.

Comment: Why use an alternate variable such as `count` instead of the built-in size of the array, `courseArray.length`? I see it as a function parameter, but wonder if it's intended use is really what you need/want?

Comment: @Drunix In my main method, I first define int count=0;

Comment: @RyanJ I called the writeCSV method using: writeCSV(course2,course2.length) and it worked correctly. Thank you!

Comment: ... and that explains why you file is empty (unless you set it later to the correct value)

Comment: If you are calling writeCSV using your count variable which is initialized to 0, your for loop never executes and nothing is written to the file. Make sure you set your count variable to something greater than 0 before calling writeCSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who just tuned in...

Change your writeCSV method to this:

```
//write from duplicate array of courses to a CSV file
public static void writeCSV(Course[] courseArray) throws Exception {

    //create a File class object and give the file the name employees.csv
    java.io.File courseCSV = new java.io.File("courses.csv");

    //Create a Printwriter text output stream and link it to the CSV File
    java.io.PrintWriter outfile = new java.io.PrintWriter(courseCSV);

    //Iterate the elements actually being used
    for (int i=0; i < courseArray.length ; i++) {
        outfile.write(courseArray[i].toCSVString());

    }//end for

    outfile.close();
} //end writeCSV()
```

1. Remove the count argument from this function, unless you actually
   intend to write a different number of elements into the CSV file.
   Judging from your main method, this isn't the case.
2. Change `count` in your for-loop to `courseArray.length`

Then, in your main method, change the call to:

```
writeCSV(course2);
```

Always be sure to initialize your variables, and when in doubt, make use of your debugger. That could have helped you spot this.

Hope this helps.